# Babel with preset-env (no options) and preset-typescript says "Missing class properties transform". Why?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I've got a fairly simple Babel config:

```js
            {
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-typescript',
                  {
                    isTSX: true,
                    allExtensions: true,
                    allowNamespaces: true,
                    onlyRemoveTypeImports: true,
                  },
                ],
                ['@babel/preset-env', {}],
              ],
              plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx'],
            },
```

This is being passed to `babel-loader` in my Webpack setup. Then I get errors like the following when I build:

```
ERROR in ./store/state/AppState.ts
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/trusktr/src/my-project/src/store/state/AppState.ts: Missing class properties transform.
  25 | 
  26 | export class AppState implements State<string> {
> 27 |   static Key = 'AppState'
```

Here's the versions:

```
❯ npm ls @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-typescript @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx babel-loader
my-project@1.0.0 /home/trusktr/src/my-project
├── @babel/core@7.9.0 
├── @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.9.4 
├── @babel/preset-env@7.9.5 
├── @babel/preset-typescript@7.9.0 
└── babel-loader@8.1.0
```

Any ideas why this happens? Isn't `preset-env` suppose to handle basic things like class fields?

Comment: looks like this one https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1779

Comment: @emrhzc It does look similar to that. There's a bunch of other similar issues in other repos too. I also asked in the Babel Slack channel here: https://babeljs.slack.com/archives/C0DFJT81H/p1587783110288900 (the link works only if you join the Slack channel I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) to your plugins configuration. AFAIK, Babel presets does not do it by themselves.

Comment: babel-typescript only removes the types. The JS language features need to be specified.